# Laravel chunk Call to a member function groupBy() on my variable

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel 8 project I'm dispatching a Job which runs and collects a bunch of data from the database, the data could be any amount ranging from a few hundred rows of data to potentially thousands, so could be quite memory intensive.

Upon returning the results, they're processed and added to a database table, and I'm hoping to have some kind of progress indication as a percentage that can be reported back to the user whilst the chunking is in progress, I have two tables, a `reports` and a `reports_data` table.

I've switched by query over to Laravel's `chunk` method, and am splitting the data collection into smaller bits as this should improve performance, but for some reason, to use my data as a whole, as if it were a collection I'm pushing it into an empty array called `$res`, but I'm getting an error so my job failsError: Call to a member function groupBy() on array:

> Error: Call to a member function groupBy() on array

I'm wondering what I'm missing...

```php
/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{

  $filters = json_decode($this->report->discovery_filters);
  $data = [];

  // create
  foreach ($filters as $findable) {
    $resultData = [];

    // query data
    if (isset($findable->query)) {
      $this->setDynamicChartOptions();

      $res = [];
      $chunkData = DB::table($findable->query->table)
                     ->select($findable->query->columns)
                     ->where($findable->query->filterBy)
                     ->orderBy($findable->query->orderBy->field, $findable->query->orderBy->direction)
                     ->chunk(100, function ($chunkedResults) use ($res) {
                        foreach ($chunkedResults as $chunk) {

                          // how to update some kind of progress?
                          array_push($res, $chunk);
                          var_dump(count($res));
                        }
                      });

      // $res expected as a collection? Maybe I can use the `collect` method?
      if (isset($findable->query->useGrouping) && $findable->query->useGrouping) {
        $results = $res->groupBy(function ($item, $key) use ($findable) {
          $date = Carbon::parse($item->{$findable->query->groupBy});
          return $date->format($findable->query->groupByFormat);
        });

        $results = $results->map(function ($item, $key) {
          return $item[0];
        });

        $resultData = $results->flatten();
      }
    }

    $res = [
      'componentID' => $findable->componentID ?? 0,
      'type' => $findable->type ?? '',
      'name' => $findable->name ?? '',
      'labelsKey' => $findable->query->labelsKey ?? '',
      'dataKey' => $findable->query->dataKey ?? '',
      'data' => $resultData ?? [],
      'structure' => $this->getStructure($findable, $resultData)
    ];

    array_push($data, $res);
  }

  // create our report data entry
  $this->createReportData($data);
}
```

#### UPDATE:

I've tried chunking and grouping, the job fails:

```php
$res = [];
$chunkData = DB::table($findable->query->table)
               ->select($findable->query->columns)
               ->where($findable->query->filterBy)
               ->orderBy($findable->query->orderBy->field, $findable->query->orderBy->direction)
               ->chunk(100, function ($chunkedResults) use ($res) {
                  $res[] = $chunkedResults;
                  foreach($res as $chunk) {
                    $chunk->groupBy();
                  }
                });
```

This also fails...

```php
res = [];
          $chunkData = DB::table($findable->query->table)
                         ->select($findable->query->columns)
                         ->where($findable->query->filterBy)
                         ->orderBy($findable->query->orderBy->field, $findable->query->orderBy->direction)
                         ->chunk(100, function ($chunkedResults) use ($res) {
                            $res[] = $chunkedResults;
                          });

          foreach($res as $chunk) {
            $chunk->groupBy();
          }
```

And this too, still doesn't seem to work in that it doesn't give back any collection, which is what I need for the rest of my code to work:

```php
$res = [];
$chunkData = DB::table($findable->query->table)
               ->select($findable->query->columns)
               ->where($findable->query->filterBy)
               ->orderBy($findable->query->orderBy->field, $findable->query->orderBy->direction)
               ->chunk(100, function ($chunkedResults) use ($res) {
                  foreach ($chunkedResults as $key => $chunk) {
                    array_push($res, $chunk);
                  }
                });

$res = collect($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `$res = [];` is an array, not an instance of eloquent's `Illuminate\Support\Collection`. Therefore, you can not call `$res->groupBy()`, as you are trying within the first if-statement.

Remove the `->chunk()` method and get your data-chunk by using [slice](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-slice) instead for example within a loop that always takes a slice of the data.

Optionally, call `collect($res)` to turn the array back into a collection. However, when having a Collection already, there is no point in making it into an array first just to cast it back directly afterwords. So I would go with the slice approach.

---

You could also - withing your chunk callback - do the following:

```php
->chunk(100, function ($chunkedResults) use ($res) {
  $res[] = $chunkedResults;
});
```

And then:

```php
foreach($res as $chunk) {
  $chunk->groupBy();
}
```

Comment: After reading the docs, the `slice` approach only ever seems to return X amount of results from a given set of results. I need to return all of my results, thus I thought `chunk` would be more performant in querying from the database and getting some kind of progress in there? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Thats why I mean use slice `within a loop`. So something like: for `$i` from 0 to `$data->count() / $chunkSize` do `->slice($lastSlice, $i * $chunkSize) ` or something like that

Comment: After I use `chunk`, loop over my results and push into my `$res` array, I've just tried using the `collect`, turns out that now that doesn't return any data back, why? Also, after trying your other suggestions, they just error, why? I'll update my description so you can see

Comment: I've updated my description with some of your suggestions, continue to get: `Error: Call to a member function groupBy(`